# Rofi not working on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, launcher, 23.10

As the title says, rofi is not working for me. I did a clean install of ubuntu 23.10 since I got a new M.2. I just installed rofi with apt and I have the 1.7.3 version. The issue is when I trigger `rofi -show drun` does not get focus. Only with the cursor, and even with that, if I click on the prompt, the keyboard just does not get recognize.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to Ubuntu running via Wayland.

See here:

https://github.com/davatorium/rofi/issues/880